# What happens to a Python list object in memory when it has been dereferenced from a Variable?

Tags: python, list, memory

What happens to a Python list object in memory when it has been dereferenced from a Variable?

Example

```
A = ["A", "B"]
print(A)
A = []
A = None
print(A)
```

What happens to the `["A", "B"]`?

Comment: it gets garbage collected. The memory is freed for use for other puposes

Comment: for how many seconds is it stored in memory before garbage collection is called on the object?

Comment: *dereferencing* means *looking up the reference*. Do you mean *is no longer referenced*?

Comment: Sorry I think that is what I mean, for example it is no longer used anywhere in the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects that no longer have any references pointing to them are deleted.

CPython achieves this by reference counting; assigning adds to the reference count, removing a reference decreases the reference count. When the count reaches 0 the object is automatically deleted.

The edge case is when an object directly or indirectly points to itself; for example by adding adding a list to itself:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append(a)
>>> a
[[...]]
```

The ellipsis there indicates a reference cycle. Python uses a garbage collector to detect and break such cycles; it runs periodically to find object graphs that are not referenced by anything else.

Comment: Would you know perhaps why if I assign None to A and I do a sys.getrefcount(A) it retutns 5000? but if A = [] it returns 2?

Comment: @MatthewduPlessis: `None` is a singleton object, Python only ever has **one** instance of that object. You have 5000 different references to it. Using the `None` syntax just gives you another reference to that object.

Comment: @MatthewduPlessis: your `[]` object on the other hand is an individual, unique instance. `a` is the only reference, the second reference is the Python stack as it passes the value to the `sys.getrefcount()` function.